# How to modify the pgfplots arrows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

The code

```
\documentclass[10pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[arrow1/.style={->,color=black,solid}]
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot [arrow1] coordinates{(0,0) (1,1)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: plot with arrow]

What you barely see is an arrow. How can I modify the arrow head, e.g. enlarge it to make it more obvious it is an arrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arrows.meta` library from TikZ lets you do all sorts of things with arrowheads. See the TikZ manual (section 16.5) for a complete reference.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      arrow1/.style={
       -{Classical TikZ Rightarrow[width=10pt,length=10pt,line width=2pt]},
        color=black,solid}]
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot [arrow1] coordinates{(0,0) (1,1)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```